# Winforms -> Visualize dragged item for Drag & Drop

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'd like to achieve the following and was looking for a sample/tutorial but couldn't really find anything:

I have C# Winforms application, which has multiple Forms within the same process. I'd like to be able to drag & drop items within and between forms and would like to provide some custom painted visualization of the item being dragged.

For example, my IM app shows the effect that I'd like to achieve:
[image]

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually physically have to drag a control with the mouse.

For example: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamroot/archive/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adamroot/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms)

Comment: Can you drag the control out of its window ?

Comment: No, but you could add the control to a form and drag said form.

Comment: You mean drag a Form then? that's the way I was thinking about.

Comment: I looked at the samples and tried the sample code and this does exactly what I was looking for. The only issue is, that if you drag it to certain parts of the screen, it crashes and leaves artifacts on my screen. So, it will need some work.